# Региональные поддомены

Tags: .htaccess, поддомены

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт, допустим `shop.com`, на котором пользователь выбирает свой город, и если пользователь выбрал например город Москва, его перенаправляет на поддомен `moscow.shop.com`. Как сделать так, чтобы на этом поддомене отображался основной сайт? (при этом url должен оставаться `moscow.shop.com`).

В ISP Manager сделал автоподдомены, но при переходе показывает такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скопировать код основного сайта на этот поддомен. Так нет?

Comment: @Erm, если на поддомене будет меняться только контент на главной странице, то бессмысленно копировать весь сайт на поддомен, тем более если городом очень много.

Comment: Парсить главную страницу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно выполнить два действия:

1) В DNS добавить А-запись *.shop.com.

2) В ISPmanger, в разделе www-домены, для домена shop.com добавить alias (псевдоним) *.shop.com.

Вообще, в панели управления, который вы используете, есть функция автоподдоменов, но она немного по другому работает, если я правильно помню.

Конечно же, после добавления записи в DNS должно пройти некоторое время для новых поддоменов. Но все существующие поддомены должны работать корректно. А до обновления, можно проверить через файл [hosts](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts)

Comment: спасибо за помощь)